# Primary key constraint and unique constraint defined on the same column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I came across a scenario where I observed that SQL Server actually allows us to create both a primary key constraint and a unique constraint on the same column. I expected that it wouldn't throw any error syntactically.

I tested it out and it seems to work fine.

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(10),

    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_id UNIQUE (id)
)
```

I also saw that it created a PK constraint and unique constraint separately.

I wanted to get your thoughts on what would be the advantages of having this unique key separately created?

Would it be a good practice to always create a unique constraint along with the primary key? If the answer is "No", in what cases would it be advantageous.

I feel like its a very basic question, but I wanted to get some experts thoughts and advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Primary Keys are by definition unique. This is redundant and I can't imagine it's anything but extra overhead.

Comment: All primary keys are unique but not all unique indexes are primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

A unique constraint is a unique index that's listed as a constraint object in the database.

This will exist separately from your clustered index (your primary key in this instance).

This can be of some benefit, e.g. for other table's foreign key lookups against this table, as the unique index created will be smaller the clustered index (if there are other columns in your table).

[Adding nonclustered index on primary keys](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/adding-nonclustered-index-on-primary/)

[Unique Constraints and Unique Indexes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx)

I think you'd have a harder time finding an advantage if your primary key wasn't also the clustering key, in which case you would be adding a redundant unique nonclustered index (which is allowed even if one isn't a primary key).

Answer (score 3):

The question has been edited to make the other two answers a bit misleading.  The edit removed the explicit (and sort-of redundant) `CLUSTERED` declaration for the primary key.

In SQL Server, primary keys are not necessarily clustered.  Primary keys have two characteristics:

- They are `NOT NULL`
- They are `UNIQUE`

In some databases, a `PRIMARY KEY` declaration necessarily creates a clustered index.  In SQL Server, this is the *default* behavior, but it is not required:

> CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED
>
> Indicate that a clustered or a nonclustered index is created for the
>   `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint. `PRIMARY KEY` constraints default
>   to `CLUSTERED`, and `UNIQUE` constraints default to `NONCLUSTERED`.

Hence, the `UNIQUE` index is redundant to the `PRIMARY KEY` definition.  I can only imagine that someone would create it first, and then decide to make the column a `PRIMARY KEY`, forgetting to remove the clustered index.  One reason this might happen is if code used an `INDEX` hint with an explicit name for the index.

Comment: It could also be that the table structure in the question is vastly simplified. Meaning the clustered primary key on the id column which by definition includes all the other columns could be much wider than the unique index. There could be benefits to having an additional unique index (which is how a unique constraint is implemented) for certain query patterns. It would definitely be a cheaper way to get a count, for example, if those are the only two indexes SQL Server can choose between.

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage, the unique key is redundant with the clustered primary key.

Typically unique keys are used to enforce unique constraints that are not on the primary key, or foreign keys that require a different key than the primary key.

Comment: Exactly. I had this point that the Primary key is automatically enforcing a Unique key in the background. I was just curious when I saw one of my colleague implementing this way.

Comment: The strength and drawback of SQL Server is that it lets you do everything a wide variety of ways. Many of them are redundant and sub-optimal. For example, you could define the same non-clustered index as many times as you wanted for the same column combination. There'd be no performance benefit on reads, a significant performance drawback or writes and a significant space increase. Yet people do it all the time (usually unintentionally)

Comment: In SQL Server, a primary key is not necessarily clustered.

Comment: Yes, in SQL Server a Primary Key can be separate from the clustered index. However, because the creation of a primary key creates a clustered index on the key, it is almost always the same in practice. One notable exception when it should not be the same, a non-sequential GUID should never be the first column of a clustered index, but should often be the first column of a primary key. You'll need to define this manually.